# auto export to org-reveal manual save?

Tags: org-mode, org-reveal

I work a lot these-days with `org-reveal` to create presentations for some of my classes.

Each time to see what I've changed and how it would look, I need to manually export using `C-e R R`. Is there a way to auto export the current org file to a reveal html file of the same name when I save manually?

If the manual save methods is to difficult, I wouldn't mind automatically exporting every X minutes.

Comment: Please do not sign off posts with "Best" or "Thanks" or your name/initial.

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt this, which does the same for LaTeX. I don't active this globally, but occasionally turn it on for a buffer. It should probably be improved to only operate on the local buffer.

```
** Export to LaTeX when saving
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results none
(defun kdm/org-save-and-export ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (org-latex-export-to-latex)))
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'kdm/org-save-and-export nil t)
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: that sounds great, but from what i understand that will work on *any* currently opened org buffer when i save right? can this be adjusted to only work as you said on the current buffer?

Comment: I think the options to `add-hook` make it buffer-local.